# Stop-word elimination and stemmer in python

Tags: python, nlp, stemming, stop-words

I have a somewhat large document and want to do stop-word elimination and stemming on the words of this document with Python. Does anyone know an of the shelf package for these?
If not a code which is fast enough for large documents is also welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) supports this.

Comment: Yes, use NLTK.  It's open source and runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you don't want to use NLTK, you can try PyStemmer. For stop words just download a list (google it) and filter them out.